# calculate Sup of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

we consider the set $A=\{0\} \cup \{\dfrac{1}{m}: m \in \mathbb{N}^\star\}$ and we consider the sequence $(\varphi_m)$ defined by $\varphi_m(x)= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$ neighborhood $[\dfrac{1}{m},1]$ and $\varphi_m(x)=0$ neighborhood $[0,\dfrac{1}{m+1}]$.

My question is how we calculate $\sup_{|\alpha| \leq k} \sup_{x \in A} |D^\alpha \varphi_m(x)|$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
Thank you in advance to the help

Comment: You have defined $\varphi_m$, but what is $\varphi$?

Comment: Sorry it was an error, there is no $\varphi$, it's $\varphi_m$. I edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the $\varphi_m$ are $C^\infty$ then
$$
D^k\varphi_m\Bigl(\frac{1}{m+1}\Bigr)=D^k\varphi_m\Bigl(\frac{1}{m}\Bigr)=0\quad\forall k\ge1.
$$

Comment: Can you more explicit the calcul please.

Comment: To the right of $1/m$ and to the left of $1/(m+1)$ $\varphi_m$ is constant.

Comment: But why you choice the points $\dfrac{1}{m}$ and $\dfrac{1}{m+1}$? Why you don't work with any point on $[\dfrac{1}{m},1]$? Please

Comment: You ask for the $\sup$ on $A$. No point between $1/(m+1)$ and $1/m$ is in $A$.

Comment: Thank you so much